# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in UIImagePNGRepresentation when Guard Malloc enabled

Tags: iphone, ios, malloc, exc-bad-access, uiimagepngrepresentation

I am getting **EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at UIImagePNGRepresentation()** when Guard Malloc enabled and when I disable I am not getting any error while converting image. I have gone through google for solution but I am not find any working solution approach. below is the code.

```
UIImage  *image, *newImage;
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"somepath"];
            image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
NSData* data = nil;
        data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        // write to temp directory and return URI
        NSString* docsPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory ()stringByStandardizingPath];
// more code
```

this is a part of phonegap plugin code and any suggestions are really helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: try adding the extension to the image name

Answer (score 0):

Information in not sufficient. But I can give you a hint that some delegate or property is de-allocated. Define it as a strong

If you can give you the stack trace it will be more helpful.

Good Luck